# What is the correct way to capture the Http Status code with Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I am creating an aspect to register my application using `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController` like `@Pointcut`, this works perfectly when my class responds normally, but when an exception occurs for some reason, the returned httpStatus is always 200, even If my http response returns 500 when an error occurs, I think this is because RestController does not set the http status, but delegates it to the exception handler, how do I fix this and still have traceability on top of the restcontroller?

Follow my rest controller

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/conta")
public class ContaResourceHTTP {


    @JetpackMethod("Pagamento de conta")
    @PostMapping("/pagamento")
    public void realizarPagamento(@RequestBody DTOPagamento dtoPagamento) throws InterruptedException
    {

    }

    @JetpackMethod("Transferência entre bancos")
    @PostMapping("/ted")
    public void realizarTED(@RequestBody DTOPagamento dtoPagamento) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        if(true)
            throw new Exception("XXX");
        //log.info(dtoPagamento.toString());
    }

}
```

my AOP implementation:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Slf4j
public class MetricsAspect {

    //@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    @Pointcut("execution(* javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.*(..)) *)")
    public void springBeanPointcut() {
    }

    @Autowired
    Tracer tracer;

    @Around("springBeanPointcut()")
    public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();

        long inicioProcesso = System.currentTimeMillis();

        joinPoint.proceed();

        long finalProcesso = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long duracaoProcesso = finalProcesso - inicioProcesso;

        HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                .getResponse();

        Metrics metricas = new Metrics();

        metricas.setDuracaoMs(duracaoProcesso);
        metricas.setDataHoraRequisicao(milissegundosToStringDate(inicioProcesso));
        metricas.setDataHoraResposta(milissegundosToStringDate(finalProcesso));
        metricas.setServidorOrigem(request.getRemoteAddr());
        metricas.setPortaOrigem(request.getRemotePort());
        metricas.setDominioAcesso(request.getLocalName());
        metricas.setPortaAcesso(request.getLocalPort());
        metricas.setUrlPath(request.getRequestURI());
        metricas.setMetodoHttp(request.getMethod());
        metricas.setIdTransacao(tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString());
        metricas.setIdSpan(tracer.currentSpan().context().spanIdString());
        metricas.setStatusHttp(response.getStatus());

        log.info(JSONConversor.toJSON(metricas));

    }

    public String milissegundosToStringDate(long ms) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

        Date dataInicial = new Date(ms);

        return dateFormat.format(dataInicial);
    }
}
```

My exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {


    @ExceptionHandler({ Throwable.class })
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handlerValidationException2(Throwable e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e, traceRespostaAPI),
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while I was able to solve the problem with a solution that may not be the most elegant for the problem, basically I used two pointcuts, one in the restcontroller to intercept the @JetpackMethod annotation value and add it to the http response header with advice before and another around HttpServlet that really is the one who really gets back with the modified http status.

Here's the code below that solved my problem.

This class intercepts annotation and adds its value to the header.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class InterceptRestAnnotationAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void restControllerExecution() {}


    @Before("restControllerExecution()")
    public void setMetodoHttpHeader(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                .getResponse();

        String origem = VerificadorOrigem.processarOrigem(joinPoint);

        response.setHeader("nomeMetodo", origem);

    }

}
```

This other class logs the servlet metrics I needed and can retrieve the value entered in the header earlier.

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MetricsAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.*(..)) *)")
    public void servletService() {
    }

    @Autowired
    Tracer tracer;

    @Around("servletService()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();

        long inicioProcesso = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

        long finalProcesso = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long duracaoProcesso = finalProcesso - inicioProcesso;

        HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                .getResponse();

        Metrics metricas = new Metrics();

        String funcionalidade = response.getHeader("nomeMetodo") == null ? "Indeterminada"
                : response.getHeader("nomeMetodo");

        metricas.setNivelLog("INFO");
        metricas.setFuncionalidade(funcionalidade);
        metricas.setDuracaoMs(duracaoProcesso);
        metricas.setDataHoraRequisicao(ManipulaData.milissegundosToStringDate(inicioProcesso));
        metricas.setDataHoraResposta(ManipulaData.milissegundosToStringDate(finalProcesso));
        metricas.setServidorOrigem(request.getRemoteAddr());
        metricas.setPortaOrigem(request.getRemotePort());
        metricas.setDominioAcesso(request.getLocalName());
        metricas.setPortaAcesso(request.getLocalPort());
        metricas.setUrlPath(request.getRequestURI());
        metricas.setMetodoHttp(request.getMethod());
        metricas.setIdTransacao(tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString());
        metricas.setIdSpan(tracer.currentSpan().context().spanIdString());
        metricas.setStatusHttp(response.getStatus());

        log.info(JSONConversor.toJSON(metricas));

        return result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code after `joinPoint.proceed();` gets executed in case of Exceptions.
You can have a different advice for execution in case of Exceptions:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "springBeanPointcut()", throwing = "e")
  public void afterThrowingAdvice(JoinPoint jp, Exception e) {
   ....
  }
```

Comment: I already tried to do that, even tried to try try around joinPoint.proceed () ;, when I do that my advice is executed completely, but even with an exception being thrown to the handler later my http status continues 200 , I would like a way to make this work with restcontroller by returning the correct code and using the exception handler.

I tested using @Pointcut ("execution (* javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet. * (..)) *)") and it worked fine returning the correct http code, but I lose the annotation data I had put in my methods restcontroller

Comment: response status gets changed when you do `response.sendError(500,"error message");` that internally sets the response's status. But if its simple enough to assume if an exception is thrown, then its 500 as I see in your `@ExceptionHandler`, in that case if `@AfterThrowing` advice is executed , cant you set the status to 500 ? Like, `metricas.setStatusHttp(500)`?

Comment: Unfortunately this would not be a good alternative, because this handler is initial and still want to put several other deals with http codes other than 500, I managed to correct the problem using two different pointcuts, I will post the answer.

Comment: @ViniciusVieira, good you implemented what you want , +1 for your answer.